# How do I bubblesort lists of numbers within a list in python?

Tags: python

Say you have students and grades as your lists

```
students = ['tom', 'richard', 'henry']
grades = [[78, 88, 98], 
          [88, 76, 55], 
          [80, 81, 79]]
```

I want to print out the students with their grades sorted from high to low, but all I've done is sort the lists themselves from high to low.

```
def bubbleSort(scores):
    maxLength = len(scores) - 1
    while maxLength >= 0:
        index = 0
        while index <= maxLength - 1:
            if scores[index] > scores[index + 1]:
                temp = scores[index]
                scores[index] = scores[index + 1]
                scores[index + 1] = temp
            index = index + 1
        maxLength = maxLength - 1
    return scores
```

The output currently looks like this, switching list two and three.

```
tom [78, 88, 98]
richard [80, 81, 79]
henry [88, 76, 55]
```

How do I get it to bubblesort *within* the lists, not the lists themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Pass each sublist to `bubbleSort` rather than the top-level list.

```
for scores in grades:
    bubbleSort(scores)
```

Comment: I am a fool. thank you for the simple answer!

Comment: Better yet, use the built-in function: `scores.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: I assumed that this is a school assignment or such, and the bubble sort was mandated.

Answer (score 0):

Use sorted function

```
lst=[]
for g,s in zip(grades,students):
    lst=sorted(g,reverse=True)
    print(f"{s} {lst}")
```